# Back button on Android Phones

Tags: android

A couple questions about the back button (as seen on the emulator)...

1. Do all Android phones have the back button as a hard, tactile button?
2. If so, is it still recommended to put a back button in your software?
3. Is it possible to change the animation between activities when this back button is pressed? I would like it to be consistent with the animations in my app.

Comment: for #3 see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12047770/android-how-to-animate-an-activity-transition-when-the-default-back-button-is

Answer (score 21, accepted):

1. All Android phones have a dedicated BACK button. It is not always a "hard, tactile" button.
2. It is never recommended to put a BACK button in your software.
3. Reportedly, yes, but I do not have the answer handy, sorry.

Comment: Thanks. That answers the first two. I've still not been able to figure out the last one. If anyone has some help there, it'd be great.

Comment: Try http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#overridePendingTransition(int, int)

Comment: yes you change the animation of activity when you pressed back button in android

Answer (score 1):

For 3: Yes.

```
@Override 
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.zoom_enter, R.anim.zoom_exit);
}
```